# Bolding part of text in logo. Why?

Tags: logo, text, bold

What is the design logic in making part of the text in a logo **bold** (eg, the logo of this exchange). When is it appropriate, and what impact does it have on the text that is not bold?

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: Try it yourself: "Graphic **Design**" doesn't really have the right ring to it, as it emphasises the wrong part.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question delves deeply into the theoretical aspects of graphic design. It has to do with how the human eye perceives the weight of something, and how that weight creates a hierarchy of importance within that context. Instead of getting caught up in all that, the answer is simple.

**Text should be emphasized (bold or italics) when it is the defining or key part of the infomation being conveyed. It subtly draws attention to itself, while acknowledging the text around it.**